# Error installing numpy "Unknown MS Compiler version 1900"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have tried installing numpy on windows 7 64 bit with python 3.5 in the following ways.
1) Downloaded `numpy-1.9.3+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` which gives error `"numpy-1.9.3+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"` and its the same with win32 version.

2) Installed `Mingw32`, created `distutils.cfg` Python Lib distutils folder. This gives me a  `Unknown MS Compiler version 1900` error. The contents of the cfg file are

`[build]
compiler=mingw32`

3) Tried running setup.py from the zip version from windows as well. It gives `unable to find vcvarsall.bat` error.

How do I succesfully install numpy on windows. Is there a definitive tutorial for windows7 64 bit + python 3.5 numpy installation?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). This makes the installation of all scientific libraries very easy. You can also use [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). Anaconda is a full distribution. Miniconda allows install all packages separately.

Comment: I installed miniconda and then installed numpy . But still I get the error no module named numpy found. I am trying to use kmeans of sklearn.cluster

Comment: Type `conda` and see what is says.